# Getting Pylint to work with VSCode-Server

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm running `vscode-server` to develop on a remote machine via ssh. This machine has no connection to the internet and runs Python 3.6.5.

I would like to use `pylint` in `vscode` for the linting. Problem is that I cannot install it the normal way, since I don't have an internet connection.

What I tried so far:

- Use `pip download pylint`, `tar` the resulting folder, move it via `scp` and install it on the remote machine. This didn't work since my local mchine has a different python version from the remote (local: 3.10.x and remote: 3.6.5).
- Use the `Install on remote: ssh` button in the vscode marketplace. This succeeds but when I write code, a message pops up that says: `Linter pylint is not installed.` When I click on install, it just tries to execute `pip install pylint` on the remote, which will obviously fail...

Any suggestions on how to proceed here?

Answer (score 0):

> This didn't work since my local machine has a different python version from the remote (local: 3.10.x and remote: 3.6.5).

I don't know if it's ultimately going to work, but you can download the latest pylint compatible with python 3.6.5 explicitly, it's pylint `2.13.9` afaik so `pip download "pylint==2.13.9"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is that I cannot install it the normal way, since I don't have an internet connection.

I think you can try to upload pylint locally to the server by using [SFTP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp) extension.

This extension can syncs your local directory with a remote server directory.